# if statement fails when true

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, casting

This piece of code is failing when I build my project. THe if statement has to check if ParkingLot is true. I thought the way to do that was the following code:

```
    <th class="small-12 large-6 columns last">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th width="300">
                    <p class="text-left small-text-left">
                        @if(Model.Point.Store.JsonDynamic.En.Motel.ParkingLot == True)
                        {
                            <span>Possibility for parking</span><br>
                        }
                    </p>
                </th>
                <th class="expander"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </th>
```

But I get this error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot
>   implicitly convert type ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue'' to ''bool''.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: try casting as bool.  @if((bool)Model.Point.Store.JsonDynamic.En.Motel.ParkingLot == True){...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<th class="small-12 large-6 columns last">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th width="300">
                    <p class="text-left small-text-left">
                       @(if((bool)Model.Point.Store.JsonDynamic.En.Motel.ParkingLot == True){<span>Possibility for parking</span><br>})
                    </p>
                </th>
                <th class="expander"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </th>
```

Comment: Yeah, cast should fix it.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. That sounds like a solution. When I tried the to run the code, I got this error: `RazorEngine.Templating.TenokateCompilationException: Errors while compiling a Template. Please try the following to solve the situation: If the problem is about missing/invalid references or multiple defines either try to load the missing references manually`

Comment: Looks like this error is not related. Can you try again after closing Visual Studio and then loading all the references?

Comment: Tried that now. When I delete that if statement, everything is running fine. I checked the JSON object, and that path is also correct.

Comment: Try without the `()`. `@if((bool)Model.Point.Store.JsonDynamic.En.Motel.ParkingLot == True)
     {
         <span>Possibility for parking</span><br>
     }`

Comment: It is the same. There must be something else then. But I just tested the code again, and it is running fine, except the if statement.

Comment: How about just `@if(True) { <span>Possibility for parking</span><br> }`? If this works, then something wrong with `Model.Point.Store.JsonDynamic.En.Motel.ParkingLot`.

Comment: Shoot. I found the error. I was missing an else statement afterwords :-)